# Can't get dbend symbol from manfnt package

Tags: fonts, symbols, packages

I want to use the famous "Bourbaki dangerous bent" symbol from the manfnt.sty package. Here's an MCE :

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{manfnt}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

Here is the panel : \dbend !

\end{document}
```

And I get nothing between the ":" and the "!".

In my log file, I can see :

```
Missing character: There is no  (U+007F) in font manfnt!
] (./panneau.aux))
```

I'm using MikTeX 2.9 with Windows 10. Thanks for any help!

Edit: I pastebined the entire log file here : https://pastebin.com/KmFgezdS

Comment: works fine for me, show the log-file.

Comment: works fine for me too.

Comment: The log file is quite long indeed. I pasted it at https://pastebin.com/KmFgezdS

Comment: Do you really need `lualatex`?

Comment: Anyway, works for me also with LuaLaTeX.